# UIImageView Fit Entire Screen

Tags: xcode, user-interface, uiimageview

Note: I looked at the other questions similar to this one, and they were either outdated or not useful.

Unfortunately there are so many different screen sizes and that makes auto layout really confusing for me. I want to have a simple UIImageView to cover the entire screen no matter what screen size it is. So the dimensions of the UIImageView should change accordingly.

I tried adding constraints to squish the image and it worked fine. But an error in the debugger said that there was an error: `UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints`

Is this a big deal? And if it is, how do I get the Image to fill the entire screen?

Edit: The game will have squares going down the screen, which the user must tap

Answer (score 0):

It might be, or it might not be a big deal, depending on what you're doing and if you know what you're trying to accomplish. In my experience, this is usually an issue if you're trying to programmatically alter the frame of a view which already has set constraints (you shouldn't alter the frame by hand unless you really need it).

Without more detail, it's hard to say what the exact issue is.